# Row Expander template does not work in PrimeNG DataTable

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to use use PrimeNG templates for the first time and I can't figure out how "let-something" works. I tried various combinations I found in other SO questions, but all of them produce with the same error:

```
Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

In my case neither "row" nor "col" is defined.
So I would like to know how let-col and other "let" works in PrimeNG templates, in  [their site](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion) there is an example with "let-car" but I can't seem to figure out where does that "car" come from?

Here's my html code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="devices" expandableRows="true">
  <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon"></p-column>
  <template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="rowexpansion">
    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:2px">
      <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-9">
          <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad">
            <div class="ui-grid-row">
              <div class="ui-grid-col-2 label">Vin: </div>
              <div class="ui-grid-col-10">{{row[col.field]}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  <p-column *ngFor="let header of columnHeaders" [field]="header.field" [header]="header.header"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use let-col in a rowexpansion template, it should be bind inside a column in a body template

```
    <p-column field="field_name" header="field_header">
      <ng-template let-col let-item="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
        {{item[col.field]}}         
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
```

Then you can use the let-item inside rowexpansion template something like:

```
<ng-template let-item  pTemplate="rowexpansion">
{{item.field}}
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Well it works fine in `body` template, but I also need the same functionality for my `rowexpansion` template in another place and it needs to be `rowexpansions` template, not a `body` one.

Comment: I just edit the answare, adding the let-item option if it can solve your issue